# Django: Multiple values in Radio Select Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a radio select form that displays addresses that the user has saved. Currently, when the user visits the "select address" template, they are only shown the 'street' field for each address that they've saved. This is controlled by the "return self.street" line below as I've established through testing. I'd like user to see the street, city, and state of each of the addresses that he/she has saved. From the list, they'll select the radio button next to the address that they'd like to ship to.

models.py

```
class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='billing_address', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True) 

class UserAddress(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.street
```

forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    billing_address = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=UserAddress.objects.all(),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label = None,
        )
```

I'm using a class based view. Here are some functions within that view that I belive are controlling the output within the template:

views.py

```
def get_addresses(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_check_id = self.request.session.get("user_checkout_id")
    user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id=user_check_id)
    b_address = UserAddress.objects.filter(user=user_checkout)
    return b_address

def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    form = super(AddressSelectFormView, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
    b_address = self.get_addresses()
    form.fields["billing_address"].queryset = b_address
    return form
```

Within the template, I've got the following:

```
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        <input type='submit' value='Select' />

        </form>
```

I should mention that all of my code is working with the exception of the fact that only 'street' is being shown in the Radio select form and I'd like street, city, and state to be shown for each of the available options. In other words, this is purely a presentation issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the `UserAddress` `__str__` method to include these details.

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
     ...

    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join([a for a in (
            self.street, self.city, self.state
        ) if a])
```

Comment: @JasonHoward "breaks"? as in `<br>` tags?